# How to store random integers generated from multiple lists

Tags: python, dice

I am trying to write a script that simulates a dice game with unconventional dice. The objective of the game is to determine which dice is better based on repeated experiments where the larger number/roll wins. Here is working example I have so far:

```
from random import randint, seed
from datetime import datetime
import itertools as it
seed(datetime.now())


def find_the_best_dice(dices):
assert all(len(dice) == 6 for dice in dices)

for dice1, dice2 in it.combinations(dices, 2):

    num_rounds = 100
    num_dice1_wins = 0
    num_dice2_wins = 0

    for _ in range(num_rounds):
       dice1_result = dice1[randint(0, 5)]
       dice2_result = dice2[randint(0, 5)]

       if dice1_result > dice2_result:
          num_dice1_wins += 1
       elif dice2_result > dice1_result:
          num_dice2_wins += 1

     return ("index of winning dice or -1 if tie")
find_the_best_dice(dices=[[1, 1, 6, 6, 8, 8], [2, 2, 
4, 4, 9, 9], [3, 3, 5, 5, 7, 7]])
```

The issue I am facing is not knowing how to store the number of wins for more than 2 dice.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, I would use a dictionary for something like this but since your representation of a dice is a list (unhashable) you can convert them into a `frozenset` or a `tuple`. I prefer a tuple since it preserves order and repetition (if any).

```
num_rounds = 100
dice_wins = {tuple(x):0 for x in dices}
for dice1, dice2 in it.combinations(dices, 2):
    for _ in range(num_rounds):
        dice1_result = dice1[randint(0, 5)]
        dice2_result = dice2[randint(0, 5)]
        if dice1_result > dice2_result:
            dice_wins[tuple(dice1)] += 1
        elif dice2_result > dice1_result:
            dice_wins[tuple(dice2)] += 1
max_win = max(list(dice_wins.values()))
die_with_max_win = [dice for dice in dices if dice_wins[tuple(dice)] == max_win]

if len(die_with_max_win) == 1:
    return die_with_max_win[0] # only dice with that many wins
else:
    return -1 # more than one dice with max wins
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you’re talking about dice with the same amount of dots, a ‘best’ dice doesn’t exist. For example, if on average dice A wins from dice B and dice B from dice C, it’s still possible that on average dice C wins from dice A.